# SharePoint file gets stored in external filesystem: manually update file location?

Tags: 2010, custom, document, library, file

Suppose I have a Sharepoint Document Library that's read-only. I'm planning on writing a custom solution that will enable users to copy a file to remote file storage. How do I change the file to refer to its new location using the object model?

**Basically I want to know whether I can update a SPFile location to point to an external location.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot have `SPFile` pointing to an external location. What you could do is to add a redirect (`.aspx`) or link file (`.lnk`) that takes you to the file on the external location.

Comment: I would prefer the .aspx solution in that case. How would I create the redirect then? Using something like Response.Redirect("new.aspx");?

Just a minute ago I found out about a content type called "Link to document". Would that be a solution, perhaps?

Comment: Exactly, use the Link to document CT, that will probably help you. May I ask why you want to move it to an external location?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'm moving it due to record compliancy.

Comment: Have you looked into the Records management features of SharePoint?

Comment: I certainly have, in facts it's directly related to it actually. I can't give out more information about the project though :-)

One last thing: I assume if this is possible in a List, I can implement a solution with the "Link to a Document" Content Type in the Records Center as well? That uses Lists/Document Libraries as well - right?